# Identifying SMD component on a dash camera PCB

Tags: transistors, pcb, identification, surface-mount

I was installing a dash camera into a vehicle and didn't realize the input voltage for the camera was only 5 V instead of the 12 V I obtained from the car. Once plugged in the camera let out the magic blue smoke and it wouldn't turn on again. I proceeded to open the camera and inspect all areas of the circuit board for any signs of damage and this was the only area I could see had an issue.

I have tried looking for this code on these lookup sites using the code on the chip, but I wasn't able to identify in order to replace it:

https://smd.yooneed.one/
https://alltransistors.com/smd-search.php?search=
https://www.s-manuals.com/smd/

If anyone is able to help I would appreciate it as I would still like to use this camera if possible, since it is still good as far as i can tell.

Undamaged nearby SMD component having the same identification code:
[image: Undamaged nearby SMD component having the same identification code]

Damaged component:
[image: Damaged component]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [Richtek RT8059](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811100910_Richtek-Tech-RT8059GJ5_C20542.pdf) step-down converter.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/DC-DC-Converters_Richtek-Tech-RT8059GJ5_C20542.html))